# Set the default settings og paper size in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

How can I set the paper size of legal as default. i.e Whenever user prints the report, it will be print in legal size paper by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can set printer properties( default margin and paper size) through the control panel. You can only set 1 paper size at a time like A4,Legal etc…

Comment: is it possible to do it in crystal reports i.e I dont want to usae legal for all the reports but for some of the reports and rest of them should use letter. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the paper type for a report in crystal report itself. From the File menu take Page Setup and you can specify the paper size there. This will affect only the current report.
Also there are methods available to set paper size at the run time also
For that please refer the link below

[Setting PageSize for Crystal Report](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/9e647fac-d5cd-42b7-a1e6-db6d6cf97c57/)